# Sheets script, prompt for email address to send sheet as pdf

Tags: command-prompt

I am trying to have a menu item that prompts for a email address to email the google sheet as a pdf report. I am almost there but I am getting an error on that last line.
"GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:[file]});."

The error reads as follows
"ReferenceError: "email" is not defined. (line 76, file "Code")"

what am I missing on this line to complete the script to successfully send the email input by the prompt?

```js
function onOpen() {
var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My menu')
 
 menu.addItem('Clear sheet', 'bigFunction')
 .addSeparator()
 .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Email Menu')
 .addItem('Email PDF', 'subFunction1'))
 .addToUi();
}
function bigFunction() { //replace 'Sheet2' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Testing');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4:P40");
 var formulas = range.getFormulas();
 for (var i in formulas) {
   for (var j in formulas[i]) {
     Logger.log(formulas[i][j]);
     sheet.getRange('A4:P40').clearContent();
 var cell = sheet.getRange("A4:P40");
 cell.setFormulas(formulas);
   }
 }}

function subFunction1() {
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Please input email address', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Gets the URL of the currently active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl();
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');

  // Subject of email message
  // The date time string can be formatted using Utilities.formatDate method
  // see examples at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format
  // and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
  var subject = "Geico Tracker Report - " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy");

  // Body of email message
  var body = "\nDaily Geico Tracker Report.\n \n";

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  // Taken from: code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
    exportFormat = pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    gridlines = true / false
    printtitle = true (1) / false (0)
    size = A4 / letter /legal
    fzr (repeat frozen rows) = true / false
    portrait = true (1) / false (0)
    fitw (fit to page width) = true (1) / false (0)
    add gid if to export a particular sheet - 0, 1, 2,..
  */

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf' // export as pdf
                + '&format=pdf'           // export as pdf
                + '&size=letter'              // paper size
                + '&portrait=false'        // page orientation
                + '&fitw=true'            // fits width; false for actual size
                + '&sheetnames=false'     // hide optional headers and footers
                + '&printtitle=false'     // hide optional headers and footers
                + '&pagenumbers=false'    // hide page numbers
                + '&gridlines=false'      // hide gridlines
                + '&fzr=false'            // do not repeat row headers
                + '&gid=0';               // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // Convert worksheet to PDF
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext)

  //convert the response to a blob
  file = response.getBlob().setName('Geico Tracker.pdf');

  // Send the email with the PDF attachment. Google sets limits on the number of emails you can send: https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
     GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:[file]});
}
```

Comment: how does this relate to the command prompt?

Comment: under "my menu" the sub function "email PDF" runs a command prompt to input the desired email address to send the sheet as a pdf, however my last line of code I'm getting an error and its not sending the email using an address typed into the command prompt window.

Comment: I was able to fix, if anyone is curious please message me for how.